# Sigma Graph CurvedArrow Edges Only Shown on Hover

Tags: javascript, render, sigma.js

I am using Sigmajs to visualize a directed graph. I'm trying to show curved edges by setting `sigInst.settings.defaultEdgeType: "curvedArrow"` and even set `type` on each edge as `curvedArrow`.

Some poeple got it working by using a canvas renderer, well I'm already using one but what is shown is a straight line between the nodes and the expected `curvedArrow` is only shown when hovered over.

I thought maybe it's default edge color is set as the background color of the canvas and isn't recognizable so I changed the background color and it's not rendered (again, till hovered over)

you can try my code at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mahmoudafer/pen/ExxoLxb)

here's my code:

```
const settings = {
    minArrowSize: 20,
    defaultEdgeType: "curvedArrow",
    arrowSizeRatio: 10,
    defaultEdgeLabelColor: "#FFFFFF",
    defaultEdgeHoverColor: "yellow",
    edgeHoverColor: 'default',
    defaultEdgeColor: "red",
    defaultNodeColor: "#007FFF",
    defaultLabelColor: "#FFFFFF",
    edgeColor:'default',
    enableEdgeHovering: true,
    enableHovering: false,
    drawEdges: true,
}
const s = new sigma({
    settings,
    renderer: {
        container: document.getElementById('canvas'),
        type: 'canvas'
    },
})
s.graph.addNode({
    id: 'n0',
    label: 'Hello',
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
    size: 5
}).addNode({
    id: 'n1',
    label: 'World !',
    x: Math.random() * 1.7,
    y: Math.random() * 1.5,
    size: 5,
}).addEdge({
    id: 'e0',
    label: '1',
    source: 'n0',
    target: 'n1',
    size: 10,
    type: "curvedArrow",
    edgeColor:'default',
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is because [sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js) is not included in the [grunt file](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js).

Add it to the Gruntfile in your sigma folder, run `npm build` and you'll get a `sigma.min.js` in the build folder

Answer (score 1):

Fixed By downgrading sigma to v1.1.0